# Prove if $17|n^3$ then $17|n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Wanted to make sure my proof is correct:

$n^3$ can be written as a product of primes $n^3=17^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}...p_k^{e_k}$
Since we have $n^3$, each exponent $e_1,e_2,...,e_k$ must be a multiple of $3$ , so we will see that $17|n$

Comment: I think it looks fine mathematically, but maybe someone could make it more formal.

Comment: You don't need all that notation. This is an immediate consequence of [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma): if $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I was writing that up as an answer when your comment popped up. I think that is a better way of proceeding. Euclid's Lemma is relevant because the definition of prime got mixed up (the first way we ever define prime integers, the property of irreducibility is used instead). The fact that the two are different in wider contexts, and other subtle issues about generalising results about factorisation, mean that clarity is useful rather than simply pedantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way of looking at it. A number $p$ is prime if whenever $p|ab$ we have $p|a$ or $p|b$. We know $17$ is prime.

We are given $17|n^3=n\cdot n^2$ so using this property of being a prime we have $17|n$ or $17|n^2=n\cdot n$. In the first case we are done, and in the second case we use the property again to show that $17|n$.

What you have written makes some assumptions - for example that the powers to which primes appear in a cube are all multiples of $3$ - that is true, of course, but how do you know it to be true? Also that if $17^3$ appears in the factorisation of a cube, $17$ is a factor of the cube root - how do we know that is true? In a full formal proof each step is justified.

---

To show that an irreducible integer (the definition we usually have of prime rational integers) is prime according to the definition above, we need Euclid's lemma.

Consider two positive integers $a$ and $b$. These will have a highest common factor $d$.

Now consider the set $\{ax+by\}$ where $x,y$ are integers, not necessarily positive. The sum of two elements in this set is an element of the set, as is the difference, as is the negative of any element in the set.

Such a set has a least positive element $c$ which is an element of the set. Clearly we have $d|c$ because $d$ is a divisor of every element in the set. $a$ and $b$ are also elements of the set.

Now notice that every element of the set is a multiple of $c$ - if say $e$ were not we can use the division algorithm to write $e=zc+f$ where $0\lt f\lt c$, $f$ would also be in the set contradicting the choice of $c$.

Since $a$ and $b$ are elements of the set we have $c|a$ and $c|b$, so $c$ is a common factor. We have $d|c$ and since $d$ is the highest common factor $c=d=ax=by$ for some choice of $x,y$.

Now assume that $p$ is prime and $p|ab$ but $a$ is not a multiple of $p$. The highest common factor of $a$ and $p$ can only be $1$ or $p$. $p$ is ruled out, so it must be $1$.

We now know that $1$ can be expressed as $1=ax+py$. Multiply this by $b$ $$b=abx+pby$$and since $p|ab$ it is a factor of both terms on the right-hand side, and we have $p|b$

Comment: It's not clear to me why your initial claim is true. Could you please expand on that for me?

Comment: @TiwaAina This is the proper definition of a prime (as opposed to an irreducible). Since we generally define integer primes via the irreducible property we may need Euclid's lemma if that is not available to us. I've added a proof, which may not be the slickest but shows how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Euclid's Lemma:

If a prime $p$ divides $ab$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$  divides $b.$

In our case:

$17|n^3 = 17|n(n^2)$, then $17|n$ or $17|n^2$.

1)If $17|n$, then we are done.

2)If $17|n^2$, then $17| n$ (Lemma).